# Programmatically changing the playback volume on the iPhone without seeing the speaker icon

Tags: ios, volume

I would like to change the iPhone playback volume programmatically. I found this code online:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

musicPlayer.volume = 1.0;
```

However, it pops up a [visual overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRzht.png) of the speaker icon, which I don't want. One approach I can think of is to check and see if the volume has changed and then try to remove that overlay.

Is there a way to achieve this or to change the volume without the overlay appearing?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845222/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-volume-indicator-view-if-the-hardware-buttons-ar